# AzureStaticWebApp@0 not recognizing deployment token from variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Hi have the following code that deploys an artifact to an Azure Static Web App:

```yaml
...
variables:
- name: staticWebAppDeploymentToken 
...

      # This steps reads the deployment token of the static web app and assigns it on a variable
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: 'Retrieve static web app deployment token'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: xxxx
          scriptType: bash
          scriptLocation: inlineScript
          inlineScript: |
            output=$(az staticwebapp secrets list --name xxxx-xxxx-$(environment) | jq .properties.apiKey)
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=staticWebAppDeploymentToken;]$output"

      - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
        inputs:
          output_location: '/'
          cwd: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/artifact'
          skip_app_build: true
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(staticWebAppDeploymentToken)
```

I get the error:
[image]

I've set the System.Debug variable to true, and I see the value is set in the variable. I've also printed the variable and the value is there.

[image]

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. What is the correct way to set a variable in bash and use it on another non-bash step?
I've tried hardcoding the value and also passing it as a parameter from the library, and that works, but that is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test the same script to get the token and pass it to Azure Static web APP task, I can reproduce the same issue.

The root cause of this issue is that when you set the variable in Azure CLI task with the command, the pipeline variable will contain `""`. For example: `"tokenvalue"`.

The expected deployment token in Azure Static web APP task, it will not contain double quotes.

To solve this issue, you need to add a step in Azure CLI task to remove the double quotes.

Here is an example:

```
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: xx
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
     output=$(az staticwebapp secrets list --name kevin0824 | jq .properties.apiKey)
     
     var2=`sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' <<<"$output"`
     
     echo $var2 
     
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=staticWebAppDeploymentToken; isOutput=true]$var2"

- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  displayName: 'Static Web App: '
  inputs:
    app_location: /
    api_location: api
    skip_app_build: false
    skip_api_build: false
    is_static_export: false
    verbose: false
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: '$(staticWebAppDeploymentToken)'
```

Comment: Or, instead of the`sed`, simply use `jq -r ...` instead (`-r` / `--raw`) :)

Comment: az staticwebapp secrets list --name <name> --query "properties.apiKey" --output tsv