# Azure DevOps + Azure Static Web App - Read deployment token from variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-keyvault, azure-static-web-app

I am facing an issue in using deployment tokens stored in Key Vault for deploying the azure static web app. Since I am using different agents for fetching secrets from Key Vault and deploying the azure static web app, I need to pass the token from one job to another.

**Job 1 - Get the Deployment token from Key Vault and use a bash command to verify**

```
- job: GetDeploymentToken
      pool:
        name: 'Agent1'
      timeoutInMinutes: 0
      steps:
        - task: AzureCLI@2
          name: FetchSecret
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: 'service-connection'
            scriptType: pscore
            scriptLocation: inlineScript
            inlineScript: |
                $deploymenttoken = az keyvault secret show --name "deploymenttoken" --vault-name "dev1-keyvault" --query "value"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=deploymenttoken ;isOutput=true]$deploymenttoken "
        - task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              # Write your PowerShell commands here.
              echo $(FetchSecret.deploymenttoken )
```

**Job 2 - Use the variable deploymenttoken**

```
- job: Deploy_Static_web_app
      dependsOn: GetDeploymentToken
      variables: 
        - name: deploymenttoken
          value: $[ dependencies.GetDeploymentToken.outputs['FetchSecret.deploymenttoken'] ]
      pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest
      timeoutInMinutes: 0
      steps:
        - task: Bash@3
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            arguments: 
            script: |
              echo "1- $(deploymenttoken)"


        - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
          inputs:
            app_location: "frontend"
            api_location: "api"
            output_location: "build"
            
          env:
            azure_static_web_apps_api_token: '$(deploymenttoken)'
```

I am getting the below error:

[image]

Instead of fetching value from a different job, If I get the value from a library group, the deployment works fine

I tried using a dummy value in the library group and updating its value in job 1 using $env:deploymenttoken but even that didn't work

Comment: $deploymenttoken = az keyvault secret show --name "deploymenttoken ", the name has a trailing space.

Comment: Due to the nature of the design of this task, the expression is not expanded. A possible solution to achieve your goal is to deploy the static web app using command/script, this way the expression will be expanded and passed to the command/script as a runtime variable.

Comment: Do you mean using AzCli command?

Comment: @TarunBhatt Yes

Answer (score 0):

All parameters are evaluated in compile time. We can create a new variable as an output and make your template job dependent from the job which generates a new variable afterwards, sample code as below

```
   jobs:
- job: BuildDeploy
  steps:
  - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=applicationId;isOutput=true]629ae9cb-95e0-46b7-8a88-a4034b68323e"
    name: mytask

- job: Test
  variables:
    newValue: $[dependencies.BuildDeploy.outputs['mytask.applicationId']]
  dependsOn: BuildDeploy
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "This value is: ${variables.newValue}"
    displayName: 'Output the value'
```

Updated source code in job 1 as output

```
script: |
          echo $deploymenttoken
          $deploymenttoken = az keyvault secret show --name "deploymenttoken " --vault-name "dev1-keyvault" --query "value"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=deploymenttoken ;isOutput=true]$deploymenttoken "
```

place below code in job 2

```
 - script: echo "deploymenttoken=$(deploymenttoken)"
   value: $[ dependencies.GetDeploymentToken.outputs['FetchSecret.deploymenttoken'] ]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Swarna, When I try to implement your sample with the help of demo_var, I don't see the value changing in the second job. Can you please review and see if u r missing anything

Comment: Simplify the sample code base foe easy understanding! Thank You

Comment: This part is working for me as well. I am having trouble in using this value in task: AzureStaticWebApp@0 (see code above). I didn't had any trouble in reading the value in second job and the value is available in powershell or bash but not in task: AzureStaticWebApp@0

Comment: Access value like this '$(variables.deploymenttoken)' on task: AzureStaticWebApp@0

Comment: I have already tried '$(variables.deploymenttoken)' & '${{variables.deploymenttoken}}' and both does not work. It seems like AzureStaticWebApp supports only env variables which is why its under the env field. Because variables from the library are treated like env variables, its working with library group.

Comment: my view env is not mandatory.  [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73460248/azurestaticwebapp0-not-recognizing-deployment-token-from-variable)

Comment: Yes its not if the field is already set which will happen if the field is present in library group. In our case though, we are fetching the value in the code. Hence, I tried moving the token field out of the env tag but it didn't work. The only other possible solution is that I define an empty field in library group and then set the value in job1

Comment: yes, this will work "The only other possible solution is that I define an empty field in library group and then set the value in job1" Good learning today! Thank You

Comment: even this solution is not working