# Why does AzureStaticWebApp@0 trigger docker command

Tags: docker, azure-devops, docker-image, azure-static-web-app, build-agent

I am facing an issue with the task AzureStaticWebApp@0. AzureStaticWebApp@0 uses docker command in the background. See image below:
[image]

We have been advised to only in-house agents and we don't have any agent which is UNIX based and can run the docker command. The problem this creates is that I need to use different agents for different tasks which is opening up another set of problems (For ex - [Azure DevOps + Azure Static Web App - Read deployment token from variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74608720/azure-devops-azure-static-web-app-read-deployment-token-from-variables/74609442?noredirect=1#comment131697461_74609442))

My DevOps team has asked me to investigate why AzureStaticWebApp@0 use docker commands in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this doc: [Azure Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/faq#do-i-have-to-run-the-static-web-apps-action-task-on-a-linux-github-actions-or-azure-pipelines-build-agent-)

> Azure Static Web Apps' build engine runs in a Linux Docker container, so it can only be run on a Linux build agent.

Since Azure Static Web App depends on Docker environment, it will run docker command in the background.

And the AzureStaticWebApp task only runs on Linux agents.